# Setting up Git Server on Windows With git-http-backend.exe

Tags: git, apache2, git-http-backend

I am in the process of setting up a Git server (1.7.2.3) on a WS 2008 machine using Apache and git-http-backend.exe.  I have been following a good tut [here](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/07/31/hosting-a-git-server-under-apache-on-windows/).  I have the GUI working, I can annoymously clone and if I put the following in the config of a repo I can annoymously push:

```
[http]
 receivepack = true
```

I have added the following to the httpd.conf file:

```
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT C:/GIT/Repositories
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
ScriptAliasMatch \
        "(?x)^/(.*/(HEAD | \
                    info/refs | \
                    objects/(info/[^/]+ | \
                             [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | \
                             pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx)) | \
                    git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" \
                    "C:/Program Files (x86)/git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend.exe/$1"

<Directory />
  Allow from all
</Directory>

<LocationMatch "^/git/.*/git-receive-pack$">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Git Access"
  AuthUserFile C:/GIT/ApacheConfig/users
  AuthGroupFile  C:/GIT/ApacheConfig/groups
        Require group repogeneral        
</LocationMatch>
```

When I add the "LocationMatch" I can still clone annoymously or by specifying a name in the URL, git clone http://jon@myserver.com

It will prompt for a password and clone.

but when I try to push back to the repo I get the following:

error: Cannot access URL http://jon@myserver.com/newtestrepo.git/, return code 22
   fatal: git-http-push failed

I have been looking at the [http-backend.exe man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-http-backend.html) for examples but can not get them to work.

here is my groups file, (this is just testing out examples so nothing that would be used in prod):

```
admin: jon steve admin
webview: jon steve web
repogeneral: jon steve
testrepo: jon admin
testrepo2: jon steve web
```

here is the users file:

```
jon:$apr1$kEKVExYx$guIF9oYV8buGhFLZr16XN0
steve:$apr1$jvgjF9nv$PvWsHH.cSOBN5ymk6NT1B0
admin:$apr1$vzXgDskN$oszCei3tkHNUgtLj2HkHF/
web:$apr1$wS0do7hb$VA9tsc9c9LwY5PcjfhdwK0
```

I know the username jon works as if I put the directory requirement on the gui section I can login with the username jon no problem, (points at the same user and group files as the locationmatch does).

I am not sure what configuration I have missed off at this point, (assuming its a configuration issue).

Any advice on getting over this last hurdle would be fantastic.

**EDIT**

I have been playing some more and here is the information I have:

if I clone a repo with:

```
git clone http://jon@myserver.com/remotetest.git
```

I can get the repository out, but when I try and push back with:

git push origin master

I get asked for my password, I enter it, then it asks for it again, then I get the following error:

C:\temp\remotetest\remotetest>git push origin master
Password:
Password:
error: Cannot access URL http://jon@myserver.com/remotetest.git/, return code 22
fatal: git-http-push failed

In my Apache access.log I get the following:

```
192.168.1.2 - - [29/Sep/2010:21:58:19 +0100] "GET /remotetest.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 38
192.168.1.2 - - [29/Sep/2010:21:58:51 +0100] "GET /remotetest.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 403 -
192.168.1.2 - - [29/Sep/2010:21:58:51 +0100] "GET /remotetest.git/info/refs HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.2 - - [29/Sep/2010:21:58:51 +0100] "GET /remotetest.git/HEAD HTTP/1.1" 200 23
```

Interestingly when I clone with the username in the URL it doesn't matter what password I put in, it will still work.  I am assuming this is because I should be able to pull anonymously.  Not sure why it asks for a password at all at that point.

I also see this in the logs error:

```
[Wed Sep 29 22:33:00 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.2] client denied by server configuration: C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend.exe
[Wed Sep 29 22:33:00 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.2] client denied by server configuration: C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend.exe
```

**EDIT 2**

I tried recreating the password file by doing:

```
htpasswd -c -m C:/git/apacheconfig/users jon
```

but this didn't help.

**EDIT 3**

the PHP config in httpd.conf where it uses the same users file for basic auth:

```
<Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs">
    AuthName "GitUsers"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile C:/GIT/ApacheConfig/users
AuthGroupFile  C:/GIT/ApacheConfig/groups

    require group webview
</Directory>
```

**EDIT 4**

OK so I can get to cloning and pushing in annoymous mode happily, but authentication fails for the push.

```
C:\temp\test2\temp\test>git push origin master
Password:
Password:
error: Cannot access URL http://jon@192.168.10.97:8000/repositories/test.git/, return code 22
fatal: git-http-push failed
```

I changed the httpd.conf to use the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/repositories"
    SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL

    <Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/repositories">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes ExecCGI
       AllowOverride None
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <LocationMatch "^/repositories/.*/git-receive-pack$">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Git Access"
        AuthUserFile "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/repositories/.htpasswd"
        Require valid-user
    </LocationMatch>
    ScriptAliasMatch \
            "(?x)^/repositories/(.*/(HEAD | \
                            info/refs | \
                            objects/(info/[^/]+ | \
                                     [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | \
                                     pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx)) | \
                            git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" \
            "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/$1"

    ErrorLog C:/GIT/error_log
    CustomLog C:/GIT/access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Interestingly, when I created a new repo (git init --bare newrepo.git)  It didn't create a info/refs file.  I had to do the "git update-server-info" command to create that.

The Apache Access logs have something interesting that could be a clue:

```
192.168.10.97 - - [05/Oct/2010:22:48:26 +0100] "GET /repositories/test.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.10.97 - - [05/Oct/2010:22:48:26 +0100] "GET /repositories/test.git/HEAD HTTP/1.1" 200 23
192.168.10.97 - - [05/Oct/2010:22:48:28 +0100] "PROPFIND /repositories/test.git/ HTTP/1.1" 405 248
```

That is when I was trying to "push" back to the repo, but they are GET commands and no POST.  not sure what the PROPFIND is, not found much info on that yet.  I think, (reading around), there might be some sort of rewrite going on, that is changing the POST to a GET and killing it, or something.  I am out of my depth at this point though.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure why "`htdocs`" comes into the picture in term of `Directory`definition.

Comment: that is the default location for Apache to serve files from.  I use the PHP gui to show the repositories, this uses the same authuserfile and does give the popup login and works with the same username and password. using it as a test to make sure Apache can understand the users password file.

Comment: This question should be on http://serverfault.com/ since it deals less with programming and more with setup and configuration, no?

Comment: I did think about this, but I found as many git questions on stackoverflow as I did ServerFault.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

OK, so hell has frozen over and I have finally got this working!

I believe there were two things that were fundamentally wrong with my setup.

1) The user was not getting authentication passed through, I found this helped:

```
SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
```

Secondly I couldn't get the physical "Directory" to work.

```
<Directory "C:/GIT/Apache/repositories">
Options +ExecCGI
AuthType Basic
AuthName intranet
AuthUserFile "C:/GIT/Apache/config/users"
Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

To resolve this I used locationMatch for both the pull and push.  This means you have to authenticate to pull and push.  If you wanted annoy pulling you can remove the "git-upload-pack" section.

Hope this may help someone else.

Here is my final httpd.conf file:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/GIT/Apache/www"

<Directory />
Options +ExecCGI
Allow from all  
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/GIT/Apache/www">
  Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/GIT/Apache/www/secure">
AuthType Basic
AuthName intranet
AuthUserFile "C:/GIT/Apache/config/users"
require valid-user
</Directory>

SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT C:/GIT/Apache/repositories
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
ScriptAliasMatch \
    "(?x)^/(.*/(HEAD | \
                    info/refs | \
                    objects/(info/[^/]+ | \
                             [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | \
                             pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx)) | \
                    git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" \
                    "C:/Program Files/git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend.exe/$1"


<LocationMatch "^/.*/git-receive-pack$">
Options +ExecCGI
AuthType Basic
AuthName intranet
AuthUserFile "C:/GIT/Apache/config/users"
Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch "^/.*/git-upload-pack$">
Options +ExecCGI
AuthType Basic
AuthName intranet
AuthUserFile "C:/GIT/Apache/config/users"
Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: Hi Jon, very nice your work. can you help me understand how you managed users config as it seems this was not an issue for you

Comment: @pollux1er I moved to github in the end.  I was only using it for my self so didnt have much of a worry with users.  Can't remember much about it now, sorry and GL.

Comment: Thx @Jon for you Quastion and your own Awnser but i found in a self test some Bugs in your Config file. You need to add the full Location to your `AuthUserFile`. Without this you get over and over again a 500 Error like this  `AH01620: Could not open password file`  My solution: `AuthUserFile "C:/GIT/Apache/config/users/.htaccess"`