# MAMP and Git git-http-push

Tags: git, mamp

I want a git server running on my iMac with remote access (from work or somewhere else). I completed those steps where you create a git repository (git init --bare) and i also opened the ports.
I successfully imported the git-files (nothing was in it) but when i made local changes (not the remote one) and i want to push it to the server, it gives me this error (i replaced my ip):

```
Pushing to http://name@[ip]:8888/gitprojects/test.git
error: Cannot access URL http://name@[ip]:8888/gitprojects/test.git/, return code 22
fatal: git-http-push failed
```

I searched on the internet for the solution, but found no solutions solving this with MAMP.

Comment: Is it related to http://rubenlaguna.com/wp/2009/09/23/git-error-pushing-via-http-return-code-22/ ?

Comment: You could check out the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/7138643/4301255