# Git over ngrok tunnel forwarding

Tags: git, ngrok

I have a git repo on my local instance. I want to access this from outside my home network. Should I create a git server and ssh server on my local instance for this? Also what is the port I should tunnel using ngrok.

Any inputs are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As illustrated in [issue 193](https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok/issues/193) or [issue 145](https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok/issues/145#issuecomment-47354705), and [ngrok usage](https://ngrok.com/usage), you can directly expose your ssh port (22), with authencation (`authtoken`).

> First, you need register a ngrok account, go to the dashboard will get a token, then execute command like this in you linux server

```
./ngrok -authtoken as80YQhzsxIIMkMFF8gI -proto=tcp 22
```

In that case, no git server would be needed, you could clone directly your repo with:

```
git clone ssh://user@ip.of.local.host:/path/to/repo.git
```

('`repo.git`' because [you should use a bare repo to push back to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26687327/6309))

The only git "server" which comes with git is the [git daemon](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html#The-Git-Protocol) (nothing to do with ssh)

You would use ngrok to redirect http only if you had an http server in front of your Git, using the [smart http protocol](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html#The-HTTP-Protocols).
In that case, you could [configure Apache to call `git-http-backend`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7138643/6309).

Comment: Thanks VonC I am gonna check this out tonight.

Comment: Found about it on the git-merge conference in Europe in [this talk](https://youtu.be/3IIaOj1Lhb0?t=12m24s).