# create a remote git repository read-only

Tags: git

I want to create a git repository, that I can locally "change" (a normal repository), but, want to share it over http, but I want that it be a `read-only` repository for the people that clone it.

Is that possible? How can I do that?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course it's possible, what OS are you trying to do this on?

Comment: for some tests, in my employee windows box.. but right now I'm putting a VM with some unix up. BTW: do you know a tutorial for do that? I didn't found anything that specific... thanks in advance.

Comment: There's [this](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-6.html) section of the git book to share stuff over http.  You should be able to just deny write permissions if you want it to be read only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server demands a valid user (ie an authenticated user) for "`/git/repos/git-receive-pack`", all write operations will be denied for anonymous user.

See [SO question "git-http-backend"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222992/git-http-backend) as an illustration of this configuration.

The other alternative is to install an additional module like **[Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)**, which would enable a much finer control on who can read/write on any repo.