# git-http-backend causing issue in pushing the code over http

Tags: git, http, backend

I am creating git repositories on my server. My requirement is that I have to create multiple git repositories on server and i have to secure them with username and password.

As there are multiple git repositories getting created i am putting .htpasswd and .htaceess in every git repository folders to secure them.

Below is the whole flow which i am doing.

a) Created the git repository with git -bare.
b) created the .htpasswd and .htaccess in that folder for authentication
c) I am now able to clone that repo any where with the username and password.

but when i try to push from the cloned repo it throwing me an error:
error: Cannot access URL http://192.168.1.2/projects/gitcreation/gitrepos/6/project6/, return code 22
fatal: git-http-push failed

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I initially suggested to delete the push/pull call to gitolite (see below), but the OP wishes to keep the direct calls.

[Jiva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1498665/jiva) suspects that `git-http-backend` is not called on pushed (which [wouldn't work well indeed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5265730/6309)) Check [for instance this config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7841868/6309) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3982493/6309).

Another check would be the [.gitconfig of the bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26821443/6309) (`http.receivepack`)

As this [thread illustrates](https://community.bitnami.com/t/after-git-push-problems-how-to-properly-configure-git-repository-in-httpd-conf-with-bitnami-trac-on-windows/20989), the issue can be a credential one (incorrect password, or password with a special character in it, incorrectly interpreted)

---

Original answer.

Instead of relying on `.htaccess`/`.htpasswd` for every git repo, it is best to call **[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html)**, an [authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#auth) in perl ([very easy to install](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#install)) which can, based on the authentication done by Apache, grant access to a repo.

See "[What is gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#what)" for more.

See my [`httd.conf` for example](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/4d77d23305c5623356955ef9f908f4ec76780bc9/apache/env.conf.tpl#L235-L250) (ignore the `@xxx@`, they are template placeholders, to be replaced by actual values later)

```
<VirtualHost @FQN@:@PORT_HTTP_HGIT@>
    ServerName @FQN@
    ServerAlias @HOSTNAME@
    SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT @H@/repositories
    SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
    SetEnv GITOLITE_HTTP_HOME @H@
    ScriptAlias /hgit/ @H@/sbin/gitolite-shell/
    SetEnv GIT_HTTP_BACKEND "@H@/usr/local/apps/git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend"
    <Location /hgit>
```

Here, for any `/hgit` url (`/projects` for you), `/home/git/sbin/gitolite-shell` is called.
If gitolite grants the user access to a repo, it will call `GIT_HTTP_BACKEND`, which is where `git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend` resides.

Gitolite allows you to set [many access rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888358/6309) per repo, even per branch or per file!

Comment: Vonc - The only last problem is facing is that we are not able to push to the code to git i.e out git-http-backend is not getting called or somewhat is missing. Else every thing is taken care of.

Also gitolite provides a web interface. So that is showstopper for us.

Comment: @Jiva gitolite does not provide a web interface, so it should remain a valid option.

Comment: ok thats fine but we will now have to change all our implementation to implement that. We are only stuck at last point that our git-http-backend is not getting called.

Comment: I am getting the error while pushing

error: Cannot access URL http://192.168.1.2/projects/data/git/myrepo.git/, return code 22
fatal: git-http-push failed

can you please help out on this ?