# gitlab: git-http-push failed, return code 22

Tags: gitlab

First of all my gitlab connection was broken by error 500 and 502. The server was unattended for a while. So i decided to reinstall:

```
#gitlab-ctl cleanse
#apt-get purge gitlab-ce
```

Installation:
https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#ubuntu1404

After the gitlab was reachable and i could create a project and clone it.
After i tried to push a new file to my repo and got following message:

```
git add .
git commit -m "inital"
git push  --set-upstream origin master

error: Cannot access URL http://<username>@gitlab.domain.de:<port>/group/project.git/, return code 22
fatal: git-http-push failed
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://<username>@gitlab.domain.de:<port>/group/project.git/'
```

The gitlab-check gives this information:
    #gitlab-rake gitlab:check

everything was green, besides violett ones:

```
Uploads directory setup correctly? ... skipped (no tmp uploads folder yet)
Init script exists? ... skipped (omnibus-gitlab has no init script)
Init script up-to-date? ... skipped (omnibus-gitlab has no init script)
```

Why i can clone but not push? I searched in several log-files, but got nothing useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [return code 22, fatal: git-http-push-failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487164/return-code-22-fatal-git-http-push-failed)